# I am trying to create a table from 2 views connected by the minus operator returns erro ORA-00600: [KGL-heap-size-exceeded]

Tags: sql, oracle, heap-size

I can't create a table from a view consisting of 2 other views connected by a minus operator. I can create a table from a view that uses a table and a view connected by a minus operator. Is this a limitation of Oracle or is there another way to use 2 views and the minus operator to create a table.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE AS SELECT * FROM VIEW_1 MINUS VIEW_2
```

> --[Error] Execution (51: 1): ORA-00600: internal error code,
> arguments: [KGL-heap-size-exceeded]

Answer (score 2):

All ORA-600s are bugs. You can either create an SR with My Oracle Support, or find the issue already discussed, or find your own workaround.

That being said, your SQL is incorrect - after the `MINUS` you would need another `SELECT * FROM`

If you still have trouble after fixing this, check the view definitions to make sure there's no self-referencing/loop going on or other craziness (like a 100MB SQL statement). Your error indicates that Oracle spazzed out while parsing it.